# Public Containers in Storage Accounts

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-storage

First post. My Powershell knowledge isnt great. I am trying to list out all containers that have the "PublicAccess" attribute set to On. I am trying to use the script provided by MS.

```
$rgName = "<Resource Group name>"
$accountName = "<Storage Account Name>"

$storageAccount = Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Name $accountName
$ctx = $storageAccount.Context

Get-AzStorageContainer -Context $ctx | Select Name, PublicAccess
```

However I need to do this on a large amount of storage accounts. In the past I have used "foreach($item in $list)" to pass things into a small script. But never for multiple lists. Can anyone help?

Comment: What kind of output are you looking for from this? What are the multiple lists? Would it be easier to just work on all the Storage Accounts within your subscription i.e. `Get-AZStorageAccount | Get-AzStorageContainer | Select-Object Name,PublicAccess,@{l="StorageAccountName";e={$_.Context.StorageAccountName}}`? If you have more than one subscription, then you only need to loop through the ones in `Get-AzContext`, setting them with `Set-AzContext` on each iteration.

Comment: Hi Ash. So the output im essentially looking for is a CSV file that lists all containers, lists whether they are public or not, and shows what Storage Account & subscription they belong too. I just quickly ran yours and it looks spot on! 

But you are correct, I need it to pass multiple subscriptions

Answer (score 1):

Based off your extended requirements in the comments, this should work. (I've not tested it and not handled any potential errors related to permissions or anything else)

```
# Create a collection for the items found.
$StorageAccounts = [System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Object]] @{}

# Loop through the available Azure contexts.
foreach ($Context in (Get-AzContext -ListAvailable)) {
    # Set each subscription in turn, voiding the output.
    [System.Void](Set-AzContext -Context $Context)
    
    # Create an object with the container name, public access values and the name of the storage account/subscription.
    $StorageAccountInfo = Get-AZStorageAccount | Get-AzStorageContainer | Select-Object Name, PublicAccess, @{l = "StorageAccountName"; e = { $_.Context.StorageAccountName } }, @{l = "Subscription"; e = { $Context.Subscription.Name } }

    # If there is data found, add it to the collection.
    if ($null -ne $StorageAccountInfo) {
        $StorageAccounts.AddRange($StorageAccountInfo)
    }
}

# Export the collected information to Csv.
$StorageAccounts | Export-Csv -Path .\myStorageAccounts.csv -NoClobber -Encoding utf8
```